# Can't find a strings on x64dbg, IDA PRO

Tags: debugging, reverse-engineering, ida, cracking, x64dbg

I'm newbie in this and wondered that if i could crack this Snapgene program.

1. I searched error strings about registration code on x64dbg and IDA PRO, but they can't find them.
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XeJmr.png)
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GfDVN.png)
2. I checked Snapgene.exe on Detect it Easy and it says, that program is not packed.
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4RX9.png)
3. How do i find the strings?
4. Why i can't find these error strings on debug program, if Snapgene program itself is not packed??

Comment: You first need to figure out if these strings are ASCII-encoded or do they use another encoding scheme such as Unicode.